# Java - data structure for storing and getting translations (as object properties)

Tags: java, data-structures, internationalization, locale

I want to save translation values in a class. Because it's to convenient, Java's [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) implementation seems like the correct key for the mapping. The problem is: If I just use `HashMap<Locale, String> translations = ...;` for the translation, my code will not be able to fall back when a specific locale is not available.

How can I achieve a good data structure for storing translations of an object?

Note that these translations are not translations of the program elements, like an user interface, imagine the class being a Dictionary entry, so each class has its own amount of translations that are different every time.

Here is a example of what the problem with a HashMap would be:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Example
{
    private final HashMap<Locale, String> translationsMap = new HashMap<>();

    /*
     * +------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
     * |         Input          |  Expected output  |   Actual output   |
     * +------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
     * | new Locale("en")       | "enTranslation"   | "enTranslation"   |
     * | new Locale("en", "CA") | "enTranslation"   | null              | <-- Did not fall back
     * | new Locale("de")       | "deTranslation"   | "deTranslation"   |
     * | new Locale("de", "DE") | "deTranslation"   | null              | <-- Did not fall back
     * | new Locale("de", "AT") | "deATTranslation" | "deATTranslation" |
     * | new Locale("fr")       | "frTranslation"   | "frTranslation"   |
     * | new Locale("fr", "CA") | "frTranslation"   | null              | <-- Did not fall back
     * +------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
     */
    public String getTranslation(Locale locale)
    {
        return translationsMap.get(locale);
    }

    public void addTranslation(Locale locale, String translation)
    {
        translationsMap.put(locale, translation);
    }

    // dynamic class initializer
    {
        addTranslation(new Locale("en"), "enTranslation");
        addTranslation(new Locale("de"), "deTranslation");
        addTranslation(new Locale("fr"), "frTranslation");
        addTranslation(new Locale("de", "AT"), "deATTranslation");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share some code that you've written so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little bit hacky, but it works. Using a `ResourceBundle.Control`, it's possible to use a standard implementation for fallbacks.

```
private Map<Locale, String> translations = new HashMap<>();

/** static: this instance is not modified or bound, it can be reused for multiple instances */
private static final ResourceBundle.Control CONTROL = ResourceBundle.Control.getControl(ResourceBundle.Control.FORMAT_PROPERTIES);

@Nullable
public String getTranslation(@NotNull Locale locale)
{
    List<Locale> localeCandidates = CONTROL.getCandidateLocales("_dummy_", locale); // Sun's implementation discards the string argument
    for (Locale currentCandidate : localeCandidates)
    {
        String translation = translations.get(currentCandidate);
        if (translation != null)
            return translation;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have your classes extend ListResourceBundle.

See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/list.html

Comment: That does not seem like what I am looking for. I want to be able to load the translations at runtime from a data source, not hardcode every possible locale into my classpath.

Comment: I don't understand what you want then... Loading at runtime from a data source is the PropertyResourceBundle, but you don't want that... It sounds like a classical "solved my problem half way, but got stuck here" What are you really trying to solve?

Comment: The problem with these attempts is that they try to solve e.g. translation of GUI elements or messages of the application and are therefore of static nature. I want my translations to function like you have a class `Word`, and every word instance has its own translations as part of its stored and manipulable data. A `HashMap` is an attempt to solve this, but it does not fall back on close alternatives if something is not available.